# Fetching latest user status in Weibo

Tags: oauth-2.0, weibo, sinaweibo

I want to fetch the latest (public) status from our Weibo account and show it (reformatted and styled) on our website.

I can use the OAuth2 API, but that only provides a temporary auth token (and no refresh token). So whenever that expires (currently every day or two), I have to manually authorize and then add the auth token back into our web app.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get our latest public status without requiring an expiring auth token.

There are a few sites that provide RSS feeds, but they rewrite the content, and they seem flakey as well.

Is this basically impossible with Weibo, or am I missing something?